# Taylor series at $a = 0$

Tags: taylor-expansion

If we are given a power series with $a = 0$ and it converges to $f$ in some interval around $a$, then the power series is the taylor series to $f$.

But what is the **taylor polynomial** of $f$ to some degree $n$?

Is it simply the power series, but cutting it off where the degrees get bigger than $n$?

What adds to my confusion is that the power series is indexed from 1 to $\infty$ and the theorems from the book are indexed from $0$ to $\infty$, so I am unsure of what terms to consider in the polynomial.

Comment: I would say your intuition is right. The Taylor polynomial of degree n of a function is just the power series trusted so that it's highest degree term is the nth power (for example, a second degree Taylor polynomial is a quadratic). It is ok to index a power series from 1 to infinity or 0 to infinity. For a Taylor series, it is more convenient to index from 0 to infinity. This way, the term indexed by n contains the nth derivative, where the term indexed by 0 is f(0). This is the first term.

Answer (score 1):

> the power series is indexed from $1$ to $\infty$

That's  an odd decision (I would begin with $0$), but the range of index is a formality anyway: what matters is the *exponents* that appear in the series.

For your main question: yes, the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ is the result of truncating the power series by discarding all powers above $n$. A formal, not completely rigorous, justification for this is: if 
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k (x-a)^k \tag{1}$$ 
then

- $f(a)=c_0$, by plugging $x=a$
- $f'(a)=c_1$, by differentiating both sides of $(1)$ once and plugging $x=a$.
- $f''(a)=2c_2$, by differentiating both sides of $(1)$ twice and plugging $x=a$.
- ...

So, if we form the Taylor polynomial for $f$ using the derivatives, the result is just $c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_n x^n$.